# Visual Studio 2017 build tools not installing on windows server 2012

Tags: windows, server, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am trying my best to setup a build server. I went to [install](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)

and downloaded the latest build tools but as soon as I try to install it shows me this

[image]

So I though ok maybe it does not support it so I went here [requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs)

If you scroll down to build tools it says it support windows 2012 am I missing something.

thanks

Comment: Do you have 2012 or 2012 R2? Only the latter is supported.

Comment: windows server 2012

Comment: k updating to r2 thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only Windows Server 2012 R2 (with Update 2919355): Essentials, Standard, Datacenter is Supported

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs

Comment: For Microsoft Visual Studio Build Tools 2017: Also installs on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and on the Server Core option for Windows Server 2016.