# Visual Studio 2017 will not install on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: visual-studio

I saw a previous post "Visual Studio 2017 build tools not installing on windows server 2012".
The dialog says: "This version of Windows is not supported." Also a link to download some patches for WIN 8.0 is included (the msi do not run on WIN 2012 R2)
[Visual Studio 2017 build tools not installing on windows server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919197/visual-studio-2017-build-tools-not-installing-on-windows-server-2012?newreg=e37ccb39bd8d4996a62137e0809ab902)

[image: INSTALL ERROR]

The "Answer" was to upgrade WIN SRV 2012 to "R2".
I am already on R2 and I have the same issue.

Can anyone help with a solution?

Comment: have you installed all Windows update rollups?

Comment: Have you enabled application compatibility on the installer executable? Right click on it and check the settings.

Comment: Yes I did that as well

Comment: look in the setup logs for more details